# Done Button not working at programmatic UIBarButtonItem and UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I am creating a `UIPickerView`, `UIToolbar`, `UIBarButtonItem` and `UIButton` programmatically. I'v set the custom picker as an inputView of a textView and everything works without problem except the Done button.

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem is?

The code I've used is:

```
// initialize picker
CGRect cgRect =[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize cgSize = cgRect.size;

_picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
_picker.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, cgSize.width, cgSize.height);
_picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
_picker.delegate = self;

// toolbar of picker
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, cgSize.width, 35);
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIButton *customButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 33)];
[customButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barCustomButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];

NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, barCustomButton, nil];
[toolbar setItems:arr animated:YES];
self.txtTeam.inputView = _picker;
[_picker addSubview:toolbar];
```

And the `doneClicked` method is;

```
    -(void)doneClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Done button clicked.");
    [self.txtTeam resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But the Done button is not clickable.

Comment: Try my code. Create button with custom

Answer (score 3):

```
UIButton *customButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 60)];
[customButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barCustomButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

Try Like this..

Answer (score 1):

You have set the selector for the button to call doneClicked: but the method is called doneClicked. Remove the : from the end of the method name in the selector and it should work.

Comment: Used the following code but it didn't worked.         [customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Does it work if you use the buttonWithType method as in the example from @TamilKing? I.e. create button with buttonWithType method and selector(doneClicked) without the :.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below:-

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
customButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 33);
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
customButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
[customButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
customButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
UIBarButtonItem *barCustomButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

just comment the below your code and modify above

```
   // UIButton *customButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 33)];
   // [customButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   // UIBarButtonItem *barCustomButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

Comment: I changed the method as you suggested but still not working. My current method is: -(IBAction)doneClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.txtTeam resignFirstResponder];
}

Comment: My current code is: YOUR CODE + 
        NSMutableArray * arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, barCustomButton, nil];
        [toolbar setItems:arr animated:YES];
        [_picker addSubview:toolbar];
        
        self.txtTeam.inputView = _picker;  Still not working.

Comment: Basically where you have written your code, i think you had written in wrong place. please check that??

Comment: Ohk no it is right just only include custom button without adding to barCustomButton and test whether it still calling or not??

Comment: Are you calling this [super viewDidLoad]; inside your viewdidload??

Comment: Yes.     [super viewDidLoad]; is the first line in viewDidLoad function.